# How does the posterior density g(μ|x) change if we find out x could only be observed if it were greater than 0.

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

Given prior density g(μ) and observation X ∼ Poi(μ) , you compute g(μ|x), the posterior density of μ given x. Later you are told that x could only be observed if it were greater than 0. Does this change the posterior density of μ given x?

***My answer:***
I am trying to answer this question, I know that The posterior distribution of θ is the conditional distribution of θ, given x. so, I believe that if x is not changed, the posterior would not change as well. then the answer is that the posterior density won't change but I'm wondering if there is a more convincing way to phrase my answer.

Comment: Poisson random variable can't take negative values.

Comment: Given that a single positive observation was made, then (given $\mu$) the probability of observing $X=n$ seems to change from $\frac{\mu^ne^{-\mu}}{n!}$ to $\frac{\mu^n e^{-\mu}}{n!(1-e^{-\mu})}$. So the posterior distribution of $\mu$ is proportional to $g(\mu) \frac{\mu^n e^{-\mu}}{(1-e^{-\mu})}$ rather than to $g(\mu) {\mu^n e^{-\mu}}$ and this will be a different distribution if the prior distribution  is not concentrated at a single value